# What does hindu scriptures say about caste system?

Tags: scripture, caste-system, gita

The major problem in India is caste system . What is hindu scriptures stands on caste system ? Does hindu scriptures support or forbid caste system ?

Comment: Yup, its the same question as Ganesh mentioned. Caste was invented by the British, and we sadly sucked it in. Before that there was Varna.

Answer (score 1):

The present caste system as it exists today is a colonial reformulation that the British created to further their colonial rule and this caste system has no religious basis in Varna concept expounded in Hindu scriptures.

Please read this essay wherein I have elaborated on this-"Does 'Varna' provide a religious basis for the present Caste System"- https://www.academia.edu/25109071/Does_Varna_provide_a_religious_basis_for_the_present_Caste_System